# How to create a table with an object type?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I can not understand the error in the code:

```
create table insured_employee (of insured_employee_type scope for (employee_ref) is employee);
```

Table:

```
create type insured_employee_type as object (
control_number number(9),
contract CLOB,
employee_ref REF employee_type );
```

Type:

```
create type employee_type as object(
ssn number(9),
name varchar2(35),
address varchar2(70),
resume CLOB);
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line : 32 in command -
create table insured_employee (of insured_employee_type scope for (employee_ref) is employee)
Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: Remove the `REF` in the create table statement

Comment: I need a link by reference.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
create table insured_employee of insured_employee_type (
  control_number PRIMARY KEY,
  employee_ref   SCOPE IS employees
);
```

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE employee_type IS OBJECT(
  id         NUMBER(8,0),
  first_name VARCHAR2(100),
  last_name  VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE employees OF employee_type(
  id PRIMARY KEY
);

create type insured_employee_type as object (
  control_number number(9),
  contract       CLOB,
  employee_ref   REF employee_type
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1539bd828107aefa2ec8a77f8794a9e4)*

Comment: Error starting at line : 24 in command -
create table employee of employee_type( id PRIMARY KEY )
Error report -
ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @AngelPensive That is because I posted my answer before your edit defining the `employee_type` so mine contains made-up fields in the type. Do not copy mine verbatim but instead apply the concepts/syntax used to apply it to your implementation of it. So for yours I would guess that `ssn` is your primary key? Similarly don't just copy/paste the `insured_employee` table but make sure that the constraints I've applied are appropriate to your data structures.